# Refactoring Composer executable file for portability

Tags: composer-php

Installing Composer locally puts a file named `composer` in your directory. I have taken to copying this file into each of my projects that uses Composer, so that I can run `php composer` in each folder.

Since this results in a lot of needlessly-repeated code, I want to refactor the `composer` file into something minimal. The most logical solution would be to refer to a class that resides in the `vendor` folder. Why is there so much code in the `composer` file anyway? I'd prefer not to put the code into my own libraries if I don't have to.

For comparison, here's a sample of code in a typical `phpunit` file:

```
require_once 'my_bootstrap.php';

spl_autoload_register(array(MyBootstrap::class,'autoload'));

// Do some other stuff here.

\PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main();
```

I want to reduce the `composer` file in each project to something like this.

I do *not* want to install Composer globally. I want each project to be an environment unto itself and not have to instruct another developer to install anything other than PHP.

Comment: Why do you care about the code within the composer executable? And how should composer itself get into the vendor directory which is created through executing composer?

Comment: I care because I'm copying that code into each of my projects.